# Is the convergence of these two series equivalent? (They come from Khinchin's theorem and the Duffin-Schaeffer conjecture.)

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, convergence-divergence, analytic-number-theory, diophantine-approximation

I am trying to wrap my head around two theorems of Diophantine approximation: [Khinchin's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_approximation#Khinchin%27s_theorem_on_metric_Diophantine_approximation_and_extensions) and the [Duffin and Schaeffer conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duffin%E2%80%93Schaeffer_conjecture). To the best of my understanding, here is what they say:

**Khinchin's theorem.**
Let $\psi$ be a function $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}^+$ such that $q\psi(q)$ is non-increasing. Call $\alpha$ "$\psi$-approximable" if there exist infinitely many $\frac{p}{q}$ such that $|\alpha - \frac{p}{q}| < \frac{\psi(q)}{q}$. (Let's call this inequality (⋆).)

- If $\sum_{q = 1}^\infty \psi(q)$ converges, then almost every $\alpha$ is *not* $\psi$-approximable.
- If $\sum_{q = 1}^\infty \psi(q)$ diverges, then almost every $\alpha$ *is* $\psi$-approximable.

**Duffin and Schaeffer conjecture.**
Let $\psi$ be *any* function $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$. Call $\alpha$ "$\psi_r$-approximable" ($r$ for reduced) if there exist infinitely many *reduced* $\frac{p}{q}$ such that (⋆) holds.

- If $\sum_{q = 1}^\infty \frac{\phi(q)\psi(q)}{q}$ converges, then almost every $\alpha$ is *not* $\psi_r$-approximable.
- $\sum_{q = 1}^\infty \frac{\phi(q)\psi(q)}{q}$ diverges, then almost every $\alpha$ *is* $\psi_r$-approximable.

(Note that $\phi(q)$ is [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).) Now, suppose that $\psi$ is a function satisfying the conditions of Khinchin's theorem. In this case, an irrational number $\alpha$ is $\psi$-approximable if and only if $\alpha$ is $\psi_r$-approximable. Here's the reason. In this case, $\psi$ is decreasing, so if $\frac{km}{kn}$ satisfies (⋆) then so does $\frac{m}{n}$. And if $\frac{m}{n}$ satisfies (⋆), then for $k$ large enough $\frac{km}{kn}$ will *not* satisfy (⋆). So the only way infinitely many fractions can satisfy (⋆) is if infinitely many reduced fractions do.

Here is what this seems to imply: for such functions $\psi$, the series $\sum_{q = 1}^\infty \psi(q)$ converges if and only if the series $\sum_{q = 1}^\infty \frac{\phi(q)\psi(q)}{q}$ converges. Indeed, $\sum_{q = 1}^\infty \psi(q)$ converges $\iff$ a.e. $\alpha$ is not $\psi$-approximable $\iff$ a.e. $\alpha$ is not $\psi_r$-approximable $\iff$ $\sum_{q = 1}^\infty \frac{\phi(q)\psi(q)}{q}$ converges.

**Here is my question.**
Is it really true that, if $\psi: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}^+$ is a function with the property that $q\psi(q)$ is non-increasing, then $\sum_{q = 1}^\infty \psi(q)$ converges $\iff $ $\sum_{q = 1}^\infty \frac{\phi(q)\psi(q)}{q}$ converges? Is there some "easy" way to see why?

One direction is obvious, since $\psi(q)$ is always larger than $\frac{\phi(q)\psi(q)}{q}$. But the other direction seems interesting and surprising. For example, if we plug in $\psi(q) = \frac{1}{q\log q\log\log q}$, then we have that $\sum_{q = 2}^\infty \frac{1}{q\log q\log\log q}$ diverges, so the above would say that $\sum_{q = 2}^\infty \frac{\phi(q)}{q^2\log q\log\log q}$ diverges, too. (I've started at $q = 2$ to avoid dividing by 0.)

Thanks for your help!

**Note.**
I have no advanced knowledge of either number theory or analysis. So if you could make your answer(s) user-friendly, I'd appreciate it. :-)

*Edit:* $\sum_{q = 1}^\infty \psi(q)$ converges $\iff$ a.e. $\alpha$ is **not** $\psi$-approximable $\iff$ a.e. $\alpha$ is **not** $\psi_r$-approximable $\iff$ $\sum_{q = 1}^\infty \frac{\phi(q)\psi(q)}{q}$ converges. I didn't have those "not"s before.

*Edit 2:* Changed to say "In this case, **an irrational number** $\alpha$ is $\psi$-approximable if and only if $\alpha$ is $\psi_r$-approximable." If $\alpha$ is rational, $\psi$-approximability and $\psi_r$-approximability are not equivalent.

Comment: I would like to suggest that downvoting a question, which someone (particularly a new user like me) has put a lot of thought into, and not even explaining why, is pretty rude.

It would be much more courteous to add comments that explain how you think the question can be improved. Thank you.

Comment: I am embarrassed that your posting was downvoted and further embarrassed that it was done without explanation.  Obviously, there is no quality control on downvoting.  In the past, I would have upvoted to reverse the downvote, because I think that the downvote was uncalled for.  However, I have been criticized for doing that, so I stopped doing it.  In your posting, the only reason that I am unable to independently upvote your answer is that I don't understand the Math.  I can't upvote a posting that I don't understand.

Comment: @user2661923 Thank you for the support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is yes! Proposition 4.7 of these [lecture notes](https://people.brandeis.edu/%7Ekleinboc/203b/lectures2010.pdf) states the following:

There exists $c > 0$ such that for any positive non-increasing function $\psi$ one has

$$\forall N \in \mathbb{N}, \hspace{1em}\sum_{q = 1}^N\frac{\phi(q)}{q}\psi(q) > c\sum_{q = 1}^N\psi(q).$$

Obviously $$\sum_{q = 1}^N\psi(q) > \sum_{q = 1}^N\frac{\phi(q)}{q}\psi(q),$$

so the convergence or divergence of these sums as $N \to \infty$ is equivalent.

Note that the condition placed on $\psi$ here is weaker than what I wrote above: $\psi(q)$, not necessarily $q\psi(q)$, is assumed to be non-increasing. In fact, the author states that this condition can be further weakened: it suffices for the function $\displaystyle\frac{\psi(q)}{q^v}$ to be non-increasing for some $v \geq 0$.

Such a fascinating, surprising result!